# Using webpack dev server for Single Page App historyApiFallback without using the default index.html file

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html5-history

Recently I had to rename my `index.html` file to `app.html` because of some Firebase Hosting related issues.

Before that, my **webpack dev server** was working just fine, with the following configuration using the `index.html` file:

**webpack.config.js**

```
// SOME OTHER CONFIGS

entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new WebPackManifestPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      //title: 'Todo App',
      favicon: 'src/assets/Favicon.ico',
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new Dotenv()
  ],

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
```

But after changing my `index.html` to `app.html` I had to update some configs to point to the new file.

**webpack.config.js**

```
// SOME OTHER CONFIGS

entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new WebPackManifestPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      //title: 'Todo App',
      favicon: 'src/assets/Favicon.ico',
      template: './src/app.html',                // <-------------- ADDED THIS
      filename: 'app.html'                       // <-------------- ADDED THIS
    }),
    new Dotenv()
  ],

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    index: 'app.html'                            // <-------------- ADDED THIS
  },
```

---

**PROBLEM**

And now what happens is that my **dev server** is only accepting the home route `'/'`. For every other specific routes it's responding with a 404.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback
I guess this is the reason why:

[image]

---

**QUESTION**

How can I solve this? Do I need rewrites to point all the routes to my `app.html` file or is there an easier solution?

If I need the rewrite, how can I write one of those? I didn't get the `/^\/$/` syntax of the `from` property. How can I write a `/**` wildcard route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback

Just found out what was missing:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    // historyApiFallback: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: '/app.html'                  // <----- THIS WORKS
    },
    index: 'app.html'
    // headers: {
    //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    //   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
    //   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    // }
  },
```

Now everything works.